# Receive Android Push notification in Library

Tags: android, push

I am trying to implement a **library** for Android devices which will take care of **push notification** in your application.

I have a server which take care of storing AppToken and DeviceToken (I can can generate tokens and send it to my server). The problem is when I try to test it (sending a request to GCM https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send the app with my library doesn't seem to receive it)

Request :

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: key=AIza...N04 (correct value generated for library)

{ 
  "data": {
  "message": "test",
  "title": "testTitle"
},
   "to" : "ewud...UySu" (token send by device)
}
```

I was following GCM tutorial https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client so I generate google-services.json (for library package) and set up everything like they say (keep in mind library) but I am struggling with the manifest (which I think is the problem).

This is the manifest:

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:name="cz.united121.notifit.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="cz.united121.notifit.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
...
<receiver           
android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="cz.united121.notifit" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name="cz.united121.notifit.GCM.GcmListenerService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="cz.united121.notifit" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="cz.united121.notifit.GCM.InstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
                <category android:name="cz.united121.notifit" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="cz.united121.notifit.GCM.RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="true">
        </service>
```

I have this code in app manifest, but it was even in lib manifest with no effect.

I rather upload whole project on **github** for better understanding https://github.com/petrLorenc/PushNotificationProject

Thank you in advance